# Deselect cell while single selection in iOS5?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Imagine a simple table view, with a few cells, single selection is enabled, that means once I tap a cell, it stays selected, i.e. blue when using default controls. When I tap a different cell, the previous one is deselected and the current one will  be selected.

Now, to make it complete (Apple, Apple :-/...) ie. to be able to deselect the currently selected cell, we can have a simple piece of code

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *touchedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (touchedCell.isSelected == YES)
    {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        return indexPath;
    }
}
```

There is a catch though. This method is only available in iOS6 SDK. 
Could you please hint at simplest most elegant solution for iOS5 SDK where I do not have this method?

Comment: What method are you talking about? all three methods (willSelect..., cellForRow..., and deselectRow...) are available in iOS 2 and later

Comment: Are you saying that `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` is only available on ios 6 >? According to the docs, it's been available since iOS 2.0

Comment: Ahh..I must be tired ...I apologize guys..I have seen a 6 there.. What now?
You hepled me (thank you), but the question is based on a wrong premise. Delete it?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. I guess if no one has down-voted it it means it's ok to leave it there. Up to you. However, if you decide to leave it there, would you please mark the answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three methods:

- tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
- cellForRowAtIndexPath:
- deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:

are available in iOS 2.0 and later according to the docs.

Hope this helps!